# Links In Sidebar not displaying

Tags: links

Ive placed a link in the sidebar, however its not showing up at all!

Any ideas? The link is the blackburn text in the post.

http://pcdconsultancy.co.uk/

thanks
Kirsty

Comment: [Something in my project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that text is an excerpt - and so any mark-up will be stripped out.

Comment: Hi Vancoder, i think you are right. Ive just checked it out to content,... and it works

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted (click the tick) so others can see it's correct.

Comment: hi vancoder, i will do this when it will let me